# ClearCache command in Symfony2 controller does not work in production environment

Tags: symfony, caching, controller, console

I have implemented Symfony2 controller method, which allows user to clear cache programatically (I mean cache:clear --env=prod) which works in local environment but not in production.

```
private function execute($command)
{
    $app = new Application($this->get('kernel'));
    $app->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new StringInput($command);
    $output = new BufferedOutput();

    $error = $app->run($input, $output);

    if($error != 0)
        $msg = "Error: $error";
    else
        $msg = $output->fetch();
    return $msg;
}
```

This method is called like     $this->execute('cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup');

The result I got is CRITICAL error, eventhough the directory exists (and is empty). After I clear the cache from terminal, the result is ok, but running this controller action ends up with exception.

```
'The directory /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/cache/prod/jms_serializer" does not exist.'
```

Could anyone point me a direction what could be wrong? The directory has 755 and all folders in the cache directory have the same owner.

The only thing that comes to my mind is that the web has a symlink, which means what I see is /var/www/example.com/web/app/cache/prod

Server is virtual with some Debian inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed it to create some really simple script, that recursively deletes /cache folder. Symfony creates it again itself.